# Может кто-то по подробнее рассказать о методах POST отправки через httpclient

Tags: c#, парсер, httpclient

Сколько не смотрел сайтов, остаются все равно вопросы.
Вот код, и он вроде бы не правильный

```
 string loginURI = "https://www.avito.ru/moskva/avtomobili/hyundai/solaris?radius=200#login?s=h";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var result = await client.GetStringAsync(loginURI);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("https://www.avito.ru/api/1/stats/frontend/fps HTTP/1.1");
           var a=  await client.PostAsync(loginURI, content);
```

Вроде ссылку пишу и http сам, но в других примерах видел это

```
            var person = new Person ();
            person.Name = "Джон Доу";
            person.Occupation = "садовник";

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (person);
            var data = new StringContent (json, Encoding.UTF8, "application / json");

            var url = "https://httpbin.org/post";
            использование var client = new HttpClient ();

            var response = ожидание клиента. PostAsync (url, data);
```

Я должен json данные отправлять? Или что, можете указать на ошибки и объяснить что и как?

Comment: От куда вы берете все это? `https://www.avito.ru/api/1/stats/frontend/fps HTTP/1.1` - похоже на логин и пароль?

Comment: c fiddler, при нажатии на кнопку регистрации, один из запросов, который показывается в raw

Comment: у меня стоит ссылка на ввод логина и пароля, я хочу нажать на кнопку регистрации, пытаюсь POST сделать. Можно было бы просто ссылку поменять, скажите вы, я знаю, но для понимания я решил с авито попробовать, чтобы кнопки по прожимать postами

Comment: у меня стоит ссылка на ввод логина и пароля, я хочу нажать на кнопку регистрации, пытаюсь POST сделать

Comment: Ну так найдите [нужный](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xiW7.png) запрос, а то вы на адрес отправляете адрес, ну подумайте хоть немного что вы делаете! P.S. Я не думаю, что у вас получиться пройти авторизацию там таким способом, ибо каждый запрос требует reCaptcha.

Comment: ок, попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Вам стоит почитать что о работе с сетью, в .NET. Например "Эндрю Кровчик, Винод Кумар -- .Net. Сетевое программирование для профессионалов" :)

Если же кратко, то, данные, в POST-запросе, передаются в теле запроса, а не в адресной строке, и сервером не анализируются, а просто передаются адресату. Чаще всего это JSON, но это вовсе не обязательно :). Главное, чтоб адресат разобрался, что вы ему шлете.

Comment: Пример тела, как Евгений скинул?

Comment: У вас идут сначала заголовки запроса, потом пустая строка, потом что угодно, вот что угодно после пустой строки, и есть тело :). В ваших примерах, это content и data